# Microsoft visual studio says "Incorrect syntax used near the word Table"

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create an sql database for a school project, but I keep on getting the error that an invalid syntax word was used near the word "Table".

```
string title = "Failed";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Stitc\OneDrive\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
string query = "Select Count (*) From Table Where Username = '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and Password = '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    sda.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 main = new Form1();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The wrong password or username was entered! Please try again", title);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you actually call your table `table`?

Comment: Yes i did, am i suppose to name it something else?

Comment: If `Table` is your user table name, put it in `[Table]`.

Comment: @TấnNguyên Thank you so much, it worked. I appreciate it! Man you are the best!!!!

Comment: That might have fixed the error message, but you still have a lot of work to improve this code. First and foremost, you must learn about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and how to prevent that using [parameterized statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Second, you must learn how to [safely store passwords](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). Then, you can make this code work better by returning a single value instead of filling a dataSet.

Comment: Explanation: "table" is a reserved word in SQL. By putting it in [ ] you make it "just a name"

Comment: @ZoharPeled do you by any chance have discord? I would like to ask you a few things about Sql

Comment: @ImperialStitch No, I'm not familiar with discord, and anyway, I'm not really in the habit of one-on-one consultant... I believe that knowledge should be shared - and that's one of the reasons I'm answering questions here on Stackoverflow and writing a blog, but that's about it - I don't do personal consulting, not even for a price, sorry. Also, by asking just one of us, you're missing the potential help of others - some of them are experts in their fields.

Comment: BTW, yours was the last question in a streak of questions spanning over the last week that inspired me to write [my latest blog post](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)  - so thanks!

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks you very much I will definitely be reading your blog.

Comment: @ZoharPeled also how does this line of code even work if it's in quotation marks? 

    "Select Count (*) From [Table] Where Username = '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and 
     Password = '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "'";

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "how does it work"

Comment: i mean like how does that Select count code work if it is in " "

Comment: It's in `" "` because it's a string. You're sending that string that contains an SQL Statement to the database, The database runs the SQL Statement and returns a result. That's how it works.